# If $H$ and $G/H$ are pseudocompact then is G also pseudocompact?

Tags: general-topology, topological-groups

Theorem 5.25 in Edwin, Hewitt Abstract Harmonic Analysis Part 1, says if $H$ is a subgroup of a topological group $G$ and $H$ and $G/H$ are compact (resp. locally compact), then so is $G$.

For my purpose I can assume topological groups to be Hausdorff, if necessary. My question is does this property extends to weaker forms of compactness, like pseudocompact or quasicompact (if every covering of G by co-zero sets admits a finite subcovering). Is such a result already known to be true or false? If not which way should I look for? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Yes for pseudocompact, e.g. It's a so-called three-space property according to the references and introduction of [this paper by Tkachenchko and Bruguera](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0166864105001768?via%3Dihub).

Quasicompactness is not considered there. (Normally we only consider Hausdorff/$T_0$ groups and then there is no difference between compact and quasicompact.

Comment: Where can I find a proof that quasicompactness is equivalent to compactness for Hausdorff topological groups?

Comment: @BhaskarVashishth it’s trivial because in a Tychonoff space the co-zero sets are a base.

Comment: "There is a continuous map from $H\times G/H$ onto $G$" This is wrong. I've asked a [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3202930/is-there-always-a-continuous-surjection-from-h-times-g-h-to-g) on this.

Comment: @YuiToCheng Note that the counterexamples given there are not pseudocompact e.g.

Comment: I know. But we need an alternative idea anyway.

Comment: @YuiToCheng I found a relevant reference. See the updated answer.

Comment: Okay, I will check it out.